# Wicked PDF - Unable to include Javascript file from Assets in show.pdf.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I'm using `wicked_pdf` for pdf generation in my Ruby on Rails project. I'm using the `wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag` in head tag i.e

```
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "/plugin_assets/rtcharts/stylesheets/rtdashboard" %>
```

but unable to load the js. It's successfully loaded when i do `show_as_html: true` in my controller.

Anyone please suggest what is missing here.

Comment: Could it be that your pdf is rendering prior to the JS completing the onload function? You can add manual delays to wait for the JS to execute.

Comment: Similar is the case while including css file i.e <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/pdf.css" %>

Comment: There's a good chance you just need to precompile that asset: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#asset-pipeline-usage